Is a Terraform provider private state global or scoped per resource?
A Terraform provider has the ability to store private state: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/private-state#reserved-keys
State can be stored like this:
func (r *resourceExample) Read(ctx context.Context, req resource.ReadRequest, resp *resource.ReadResponse) {
    
    value := []byte(`{"valid": "json", "utf8": "safe"}`)
    
    diags := resp.Private.SetKey(ctx, "key", value)
    
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
}


The state can then be read like this:
func (r *resourceExample) Read(ctx context.Context, req resource.ReadRequest, resp *resource.ReadResponse) {
    
    value, diags := req.Private.GetKey(ctx, "key")
    
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    
    if value != nil {
        // value will be []byte.
        ... 
    }
}


Is this state scoped to the resource, meaning that each resource can have its own version of key, or is this state scoped to the provider, meaning that the value of key is available to all resources once it has been set?
If the state is scoped to the resource, is there an alternative mechanism for data to be shared between resources?

A "read" request like this is always for what Terraform Core calls a "resource instance", which is distinguished from "resource" if you use count and for_each where a single resource block then zero or more instances. Both the attributes that are exported for use elsewhere in the module and the "private" data you're referring to then belong to just that resource instance. Providers sometimes use this to track uninteresting internal details that they will need to take actions based on this object again later; most of the time it's unnecessary, and the exported attributes are sufficient.

@MartinAtkins Could you move this comment from the question to the answer, or suggest an edit, as the comment does a good job of rephrasing and expanding on details for the answer?

I suppose I did lightly answer the question in what I wrote for that comment but I had intended this more as some clarifying context than a full answer, since your answer was already present and already covered the direct answer to the question. However, I suppose I can write a more full-fledged version of it as an answer.

A "read" request like this is always for what Terraform Core calls a "resource instance", which is distinguished from "resource" if you use count and for_each where a single resource block then zero or more instances.
Both the attributes that are exported for use elsewhere in the module and the "private" data you're referring to then belong to just that resource instance.
Providers sometimes use this to track uninteresting internal details that they will need to take actions based on this object again later; most of the time it's unnecessary, and the exported attributes are sufficient.
Terraform offers no "provider-global" means of persisting data from plan to apply or from one plan/apply round to the next, but if you want to share data between resource types in your provider only in a transient way during a single Terraform phase then a typical strategy would be to have your resource type implement ResourceWithConfigure, save the ProviderData object as a field in the resource type, and then arrange for the necessary data to be stored inside that object.
All resource objects belonging to the same provider instance will share the same ProviderData value, so if that value includes a pointer to a shared object then mutations to that object will be visible to all holders of that object. If you'll be mutating that data after it's initially created then be sure to use suitable Go synchronization primitives to avoid data races, because the framework accepts and executes multiple concurrent requests to the same provider.
